# Google host getting unreachable after pinging 10-12 times

Tags: networking, fedora, networkmanager, isc-dhcpd

I have Fedora Linux on Samsung Artik 5 board. I have made the configuration from DHCP to static. Through WiFi I have connected Internet to the board. When I ping Google, it's pinging, but after 10-15 times of pinging the connection is getting lost and its giving as host unreachable.

I have tested it in both DHCP and static as-well. But every time after successful pinging to the Google server it's getting lost as host unreachable.

As I have troubleshooted it's rerouting the network manager from `Wlan0` to Ethernet automatically and the connection is getting dropped.

Comment: We need a bit more information. Have you tried to run a traceroute? It may be that at some point your pings are being blocked.

Comment: and everything else except google still working?